# Multiplication and division of a pair of real numbers

Tags: rational-numbers

Suppose that you have any two real numbers: $x_1$ and $x_2$ (different from $0$).

If we know that the product $x1x2$ is rational and the division $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ is also rational, is it possible to show that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are rational as well?

Many thanks!

Comment: What if you specify $x\ne y$ and both product and quotient are rational?

Comment: @Raffaele No, $x=√12$, $y=√3$. Then $xy= √36 = 6$ and $x/y = √4=2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Here is a counter example: $$x_1=x_2 = √{2}$$

with

\begin{align*}
x_1x_2 &= 2 \\
\frac{x_1}{x_2} &= 1
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you too for this :-)

Answer (score 2):

No. You could take $x_1=x_2=\sqrt2$.

Comment: Beat you by 11 seconds ;)

Comment: Thank you for the fast response :-D